# Open/LibreElec won't boot from hd

Tags: openelec

I made a libreElec usb drive. The live system is working fine, but installing it does not work:

The installation on my disk seems to work fine, but when  I reboot and select that disk as boot device I get a black screen with "Reeboot and select proper boot device". What is going wrong?
The same with OpenElec.

Comment: AFAIK it's important to `dd` the openelec image to, for example `of=/dev/sdb`, putting it to `/dev/sdb1` could lead to that issue. After `dd` completes you need to run `sync` and wait until all data is written to the device/usb-stick before removing it.